# WP custom taxonomy description by term

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

Seen a lot of posts elsewhere, but nothing quite hitting the mark.

I need to echo the description of a specific term of a custom taxonomy related to a custom post type.

Right now, I'm doing the following loop successfully to pull content for related custom posts per term (in this case my custom post type is 'rental_gear' and my term is 'cameras':

```
<?  $args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'rental_gear',
    'type'    => 'cameras',
    'order'    => 'ASC'
    );              

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

?>
    <li><a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>">&rsaquo; <? the_title(); ?></a></li>   
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Can I pull the term's description in this loop?
I've tried the 'get_term' function and pulling '$term->description;' but those are related to the post, and this is on an overview page listing information from many posts (hence the use of the loop)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the name of your custom taxonomy, so replace `your-taxonomy`. This will query ALL `rental_gear` posts that have the `camera` term in `your-taxonomy`.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'rental_gear',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'camera'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```